# How to install pandas on python3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm running 'sudo apt-get install python3-pandas' and am met with the following errors:

Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-pandas all 1.3.5+dfsg-3
404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/pandas/python3-pandas_1.3.5%2bdfsg-3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

.............. Any ideas on how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Is there particular reason why you're trying to install pandas with your system package manager instead of directly as a Python package via pip?

Comment: The link: https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/pandas/ does not have the file you're looking for "pandas+dfsg-3_all.deb". I would suggest installing python packages the way @Brian61354270 suggested

Comment: Thank you for the advice, disclaimer I’m a complete beginner to kali and Python so any advice in layman’s terms would be greatly appreciated

Comment: All sorted now! thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can install pandas with python pip:
`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
then run:
`pip3 install pandas`